# Check when user has launched android browser

Tags: android

I am currently developing an Android app where I need to do some action when the browser is launched.

What I want is that when the user launches the android browser on their phone my App creates a notification to allow them to launch my app.

How can I check to see if the browser has been opened. I assume I would need to have some sort of background service.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Please let us know what the app is so we can make very, very certain we don't install it. That sounds abusive.

Comment: It is not intended to be abusive. The app is to be used with the browser and the user can enable that feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no broadcasts that are sent out to inform you of other apps starting and stopping. Mostly, this is for privacy reasons, as I understand it.

You are welcome to talk to alternative browser makers, particularly open source ones, to see if they have any sort of architecture for extending their browsers with features such as you wish to implement.

Comment: i've already implemented this feature using logcat mechanism and it works fine for me. i don't deny that android doesn't provide any API to detect this, but i found a workaround to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it by keeping a watch over logcat